# @dimen/activity error, trying to figure out why

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am taking an android beginners course through udacity. I just copy and pasted this code for an app but it already has errors without any edits. It was supposed to work right away. The primary problem seems to be with these lines in the xml . . .

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

I am unfamiliar with `@dimen/activity` so any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mango sorbet"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Blueberry pie"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Chocolate lava cake"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="printToLogs"
        android:text="Print menu to logs" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually if someone would just tell me how I can add a file to my values folder that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a `dimens.xml` file in the `values` folder of your project. The content of `dimens.xml` file might look like the following.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

The `dimens.xml` file usually contains the constant values of different dimensions that you are going to use in your project. You might also write the lines mentioned above in the following way.

```
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

This will also work just fine. You put the values in the `dimens.xml` file to use them in a more readable and meaningful manner.

**Update**

To create a `dimens.xml` file in your values folder, go to your project folder. Find the `res` folder and then find the `values` folder. If the `values` folder does not exist, then create one.

Then right click on the values folder and then press `New` and then `Values Resource File`.

[image]

Enter the name of the resource file as `dimens.xml` and then press okay. Paste the content stated above in your `dimens.xml` file.

[image]